# Why can't WP7 webbrowser display video?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an application in which I want a webview ( WebBrowser ) to open a site, which I think is one of the, if not exclusive functions of a webbrowser. 
But it does not display video's, and some of the other media is scrambled too. Any idea for that? 
P.S. I am not talking about the webbrowser app, I am talking about the webview, implemented inside an aplication that is not working properly.

Comment: What is the video format you are trying to view?

Comment: @JamieKeeling I honoustly don't know, in the html, it just specifies a url inside an iframe:
<p><iframe width="760" height="460" src="http://somelink" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></p>

Comment: So you should open that link and see what is in there!

Comment: @JamieKeeling I'm working for a client, and I am not sure they like it if I publicly share this link.

Comment: @RenaudDumont It simply redirects me to a streaming video site, like Youtube, but does not give me any information on what the format is.

Comment: Did you try setting that media as the source of a MediaElement? Here are the supported codecs for Windows Phone: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the media is picked up by the appropriate media handler. If the video doesn't play in the `WebBrowser` control, it most likely means that its format is simply not supported.